# explain this line testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName

Tags: groovy, soapui

i am new to groovy.I am not able to understand what testRunner and testCase actually are? I know that why we are using them.but how they working here.

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
import java.lang.*
import java.io.*
def ac,dc,class1,cn,dd,fn,not
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader (new FileReader (new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\data1.csv")))
def rows = br.readLines()
def rowSize = rows.size()
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("rows",rowSize.toString())
def i = Integer.parseInt(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").getPropertyValue("count"))
if (i<rowSize)
{
      String []row= rows[i].split(",")
      dc=row[1]
      ac=row[2]
      class1=row[3]
      cn=row[4]
      dd=row[5]
      not=row[6]
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("dc",dc)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("ac",ac)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("class1",class1)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("cn",cn)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("dd",dd)
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties").setPropertyValue("not",not)
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-scripts.html)?

Comment: also, you don't need to `import` `java.lang.*` or `java.io.*`

Comment: Also, you never close your `BufferedReader`...  Try:  `def rows = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\data1.csv").withReader { it.readLines() }`...  That will close it for you, and return the lines into the `rows` variable

Comment: thanks tim_yates..for help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`testRunner` is a special object which `SOAPUI` put in the context to give the ability to access different properties directly related to the test execution. For example as you also ask to access `testCase` property. In this case the `testCase` is a property which holds the test objects currently running an allows you to "play" with them. In the [SOAPUI documentation](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/working-with-scripts.html) all this stuff is well explained.

Besides the @tim_yates comments about your code think also to use a variables to keep your code clean and more readable instead of accessing the same all the time using the getters, in fact your code could be rewritten as:

```
def ac,dc,class1,cn,dd,fn,not

def rows = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\data1.csv").withReader{ it.readLines() }
def rowSize = rows.size()

def myProps = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties")

myProps.setPropertyValue("rows",rowSize.toString())

def i = Integer.parseInt(myProps.getPropertyValue("count"))

if (i<rowSize)
{
    String [] row= rows[i].split(",")
    // Note that array are 0-based index and your accessing directly
    // the second position
    dc=row[1]
    ac=row[2]
    class1=row[3]
    cn=row[4]
    dd=row[5]
    not=row[6]
    myProps.setPropertyValue("dc",dc)
    myProps.setPropertyValue("ac",ac)
    myProps.setPropertyValue("class1",class1)
    myProps.setPropertyValue("cn",cn)
    myProps.setPropertyValue("dd",dd)
    myProps.setPropertyValue("not",not)
}
```

Another improvement could be to create a map using the property names and values to iterate thought it to set the property values:

```
def ac,dc,class1,cn,dd,fn,not

def rows = new File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\data1.csv").withReader{ it.readLines() }
def rowSize = rows.size()

def myProps = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("MyProperties")

myProps.setPropertyValue("rows",rowSize.toString())

def i = Integer.parseInt(myProps.getPropertyValue("count"))

if (i<rowSize)
{
    def values = rows[i].split(",")
    // I start with "notUsed" since in original code [0] postion is not used
    def names = ["notUsed","dc","ac","class1","cn","dd","not"]
    // create a map an iterate over it
    [names,values].transpose().collectEntries { it }.each{ name, value ->
        myProps.setPropertyValue(name,value);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps,